# Migrate wordpress site to a docker container (local)

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to migrate a Wordpress site to a docker container to make a replica of my site and make test with things I want to test. The problem comes when I load the database script.

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
     MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
     MYSQL_USER: wordpress
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks: 
     - mynetwork1
    volumes:
     - ./mylocalfolderdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:4.9.8
    ports:
     - 8111:80
    restart: always
    depends_on:
     - db
   environment:
     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
     WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
     WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
   networks: 
     - mynetwork1
   volumes:
     - ./mylocalforlderwp:/var/www/html

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
     - 8222:80
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
     - db
    environment:
     PMA_HOST: db:3306
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
    networks:
     - mynetwork1

networks: 
  mynetwork1:

volumes:
  mylocalfolderwp:
  mylocalfolderdb:
```

In **mylocalfolderdb** volume there is a sql script that load my database. In **mylocalfolderwp** volume there are multiple Wordpress folders and files(with the plugins and themes).

At the end of the sql script I execute this to update routes:

```
UPDATE 8S2rzU_options SET option_value = replace(option_value,"https://myOnlineSite.es","http://127.0.0.1")
 WHERE option_name = "home" OR option_name = "siteurl";
 UPDATE 8S2rzU_posts SET guid = replace(guid,"https://myOnlineSite.es","http://127.0.0.1");
 UPDATE 8S2rzU_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content,"https://myOnlineSite.es","http://127.0.0.1");
 UPDATE 8S2rzU_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,"https://myOnlineSite.es","http://127.0.0.1");
 UPDATE 8S2rzU_bp_activity SET action = replace(action,"https://myOnlineSite.es","http://127.0.0.1");
 UPDATE 8S2rzU_bp_activity SET primary_link = replace(primary_link, "https://myOnlineSite.es","http://127.0.0.1");
 UPDATE 8S2rzU_bp_activity SET content = replace(content,"https://myOnlineSite.es","http://127.0.0.1");
 UPDATE 8S2rzU_bp_activity_meta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,"https://myOnlineSite.es","http://127.0.0.1");
 UPDATE 8S2rzU_bp_user_blogs_blogmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, "https://myOnlineSite.es","http://127.0.0.1");
```

Now I go to `127.0.0.1:8111` and it no works it throws me MIME exception that  and dont anything of Wordpress.

[image]

I have tried to modify `.htaccess` file, disable plugins and themes in the database but nothing of that works to me. Dont know what to do now.

If I disable plugins and themes warnings dont appear, obiusly. 
If I enter to `localhost:8111/wp-admin` its shows a blank page.

If you need more info, ask me.

Comment: Can you please check and re-indent your compose file correctly ? The currently displayed version does not respect compose file reference and no one can be sure there is not an error there that has an influence on your current result.

Comment: Sorry for the long time I didnt response (vacation time). compose file is not the problem, It works perfectly, if I start the compose with default wp database.

Comment: @zeitounator re-indent fixed, sorry for the long time